# Equations messed up with large spaces in between. Numbering Is not adjacent to equation. Report due tonight

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

In two sections of my report I have used `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`

In the first section the equations looked fine but in the second section they were messed up.

The following are pictures and codes for the good section and bad section respectively.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjCXE.jpg

```
At $x=0,$ 

\begin{equation}
 k_1u = AE\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

At $x=L,$ 

\begin{equation}
 k_2u = -AE\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}
\end{equation}
% =================================================
\begin{equation} 

m_2\ddot{x_2}+k_1x_2-k_2(x_3+L_2\theta-x_2)+m_2g= F_2-c_1\dot{x_2}+c_2(\dot{x_3}-L_2\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_2})

\end{equation}
For $x_3$, 

\begin{equation} 

M\ddot{x_3}+k_2(x_3-L_1\theta-x_1)+k_2(x_3+L_2\theta-x_2) + Mg = +c_2(\dot{x_3}+L_2\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_2})-c_2(x_3-L_1\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_1})

\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Load the `amsmath` package and use the`multline` environment for the last equation. Also: never insert blank lines in displayed equations.

Comment: Don't insert a blank line *before* an equation either.  And only put a blank line after an equation if the following text begins a new paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

That is probably because you have spaces between `\begin{equation}` and your equation.

For example,

```latex
\begin{equation} 
m_2\ddot{x_2}+k_1x_2-k_2(x_3+L_2\theta-x_2)+m_2g= F_2-c_1\dot{x_2}+c_2(\dot{x_3}-L_2\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_2})
\end{equation}
```

compiles correctly.

In addition to this, you might want to use `multline` (break automatically) or `split` (break manually) in order for your equations to be displayed nicely. That requires the `amsmath` package.

Example with your second equation:

```latex
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
M\ddot{x_3}+k_2(x_3-L_1\theta-x_1)+k_2(x_3+L_2\theta-x_2) + Mg = 
 & +c_2(\dot{x_3}+L_2\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_2})\\
 & -c_2(x_3-L_1\dot{\theta}-\dot{x_1})
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Don't hesitate to mark my answer as accepted if it helped you